# Reduce the size of the asp.net application file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net web application and the size of the application is about `16.6Mb`,the two criteria for the size increase is that I used `itextsharp.dll` file to display a `pdf` and also `ajaxtoolkit.dll` for displaying the calender so that the total application measures about `16.6mb`,Is there any method to reduce the size of the file?

Comment: It made me to present this issue because i had another web application  which measured about 3MB,So compared to that web application i feel like its a bit larger in size

Comment: @SatwikMn - sure, it might be.  I think itextsharp.dll is around 5MB alone.  Measuring deployment sizes between apps that are completely different is a poor and senseless metric. The only thing that matters to end users is actual downloaded HTML page size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean that the size it too much?  That is your total application deployment size has nothing to do with how much data the client (people going to your website) have to download.  Entity Framework alone (with all of the globalization things it brings in from NuGet) is like 3 or 4 MB.  As long as your application is responsive, error resistant and doesn't send 1MB per request, application deployment size means nothing unless you are distributing your web app on 3.5" floppy disk :)

Your primary concern should be how much data the end user has to download with each request.  You can easily manage identifying that with Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  There is no magic number for me to put here for you to target,  but again, total compiled deployment size has no bearing on the amount of data a user had to download per request.

Answer (score 2):

Your users will only ever download the HTML and static resources your application uses. 16MB of on-disk size is tiny.

For example, here is a screenshot of one of our smaller Web Applications:

[image: OCW size]

Don't worry about 16MB :)

Comment: Sheesh, and I thought our 35 MB app was a small one :)